# Screen configuration not saved after first reboot

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

PROBLEM - When installing UBUNTU Natty on my friends Laptop with a HDMI cable attached to both TV and Laptop both screens echo each other BUT when reboot has taken place nothing is displayed on the external screen.

Another user has reported the same problem so far !

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1764389&highlight=hdmi  -> Gives a clearer description of what we are both experiencing

The UBUNTU/Natty install drives both screens but the first reboot does not ?

Any ideas anyone

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately and thank you for your prompt response ! The problem appears to lie with the external monitors ( LG screen ) EDID not being seen correctly and also unavailable when boot is completed, so when monitors is selected as you kindly suggest all options are greyed out and only one monitor is seen as unknown .

Looks like I will be either setting up TwinView or separate instances of X server for each screen and obtaining ( powerstrip ) and saving both edids and pointing to them and editing `xorg.conf` to ignore the edid provided, which is what I have done so far !. Now I have 1 X desktop `640 * 480` on external LG  ( very big ) and 6 tiled screens on laptop in `1366 * 768`.

I believe I have to provide refresh rate and resolutions manually.

Answer (score 0):

Search and open up the **Monitors** application from the dash and click on **detect display**.Ubuntu should come up again on the external display.